# Checking for condition present in multiple rows

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, repeat, trading

I have a dataframe with columns LastPrice and KCT. The code then creates a third column, SignalBinary, and records on it a 1 when LastPrice > KCT for three consecutive rows.

(e.g. records a 1 in SignalBinary[1] when 
LastPrice[1] > KCT[1] AND LastPrice[2] > KCT[2] AND LastPrice[3] > KCT[3], and so on for every row)

```
df <- data.frame(LastPrice = c( 1221, 1220, 1220, 1217, 1216,  1218 , 1216, 1216, 1217, 1220, 1219, 1218, 1220, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1218, 1207, 1206, 1205), KCT = c( 1218, 1218, 1219, 1218, 1221,  1217 , 1217, 1216, 1219, 1216, 1217, 1216, 1219, 1217, 1218, 1217, 1217, 1217, 1219, 1217))

for(j in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$SignalBinary[j] <- ifelse (  
    df$LastPrice[j] > df$KCT[j] 
    & df$LastPrice[j+1] > df$KCT[j+1] 
    & df$LastPrice[j+2] > df$KCT[j+2],
    1, 0)}
```

It works fine. But it is very basic. If I wanted to check for example LastPrice > KCT on 100 consecutive rows, I would need to write down the condition 100 times. Not ideal. Hence **I would like to rewrite the code to be able to specify variable RowsToCheck = X, so as to check for the condition in X rows, without having to write the condition X times**.

A for loop would work if I were to be checking for LastPrice > KCT in *any* 3 consecutive rows (i.e. using OR operators), rather than  in 3 consecutive rows (i.e. using AND operators).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can do this simply (and fast!) with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, check := as.integer(LastPrice > KCT)]
df[, Roll := Reduce('+',shift(check, 0:2L, type = "lead")) >= 3]
```

Just change the `0:2` to `0:99` or `0:n`, and the `>=3` condition, and you are good to go.

**EDIT:** As Frank points out, you can also use:

```
 df[, Roll := do.call(pmin, shift(check, 0:2, type="lead"))]
```

I'm inclined to prefer this method as you only need to change one input as you vary the number of rows.

I should also point out that this is extendable to the lagging case by changing the type argument to `"lag"`

Comment: Does the job perfectly. Much appreciated, thanks a lot! Prefer Psidom's code using the for loop as it looks cleaner and doesn't require loading additional libraries. Will be comparing the performance of both solutions on a very large dataset. Understand for loops may actually be better avoided in R if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is not a big issue, this will also work from the original question.

```
for(j in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$SignalBinary[j] <- ifelse(all(df$LastPrice[j:(j+n)] > df$KCT[j:(j+n)]), 1, 0)
}
```

where `n` will be the number of consecutive rows to check, and replace `all` with `any` if it is OR operation.

Another way to do it in `dplyr` package.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(SignalBinary = as.integer(rollsum(LastPrice > KCT, n, align = "left", fill = 0) == n))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect, though n must be equal to "consecutive rows to check minus 1", rather than "consecutive rows to check". I actually prefer this code above others (maybe because I'm new to R and like loops). Just realized stackoverflow only allows one answer as best answer. I keep on reading how R does not handle loops well. I will be testing performance of both solutions on a dataframe with 400,000 rows, it will be interesting to see the difference.

Comment: 2nd solution works perfect as well (this time with n defined as consecutive rows to check). Thanks a lot! I will be testing all offered solutions for performance in a large database and implement the faster, assuming noticeable performance differences. Lacking noticeable performance differences, for loop it is.

Comment: If you are running for very large data set, there is probably going to be a performance issue. You'd better use `data.table` or `dplyr` package. Here is another option `library(data.table); library(dplyr); df <- df %>% mutate(SignalBinary = Reduce("&", shift(LastPrice > KCT, 0:2, type = "lead")))`. Feel free to accept the answer by Chris. I think he gives a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution in base R is the following:

```
check_rows = function(data, n) {
    data$Check = NA
    counter = 0
    for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
        if (data$LastPrice[i] > data$KCT[i]) {
            counter = counter + 1
            if (counter == n) { # change this to counter >= n if applicable
                data$Check[i] = 1
            }
        } else {
            counter = 0
        }
    }
    data
}
```

Obviously not as clean as the `data.table` solution, nor likely to be the best base R solution either.

Comment: Maybe you want `>= n` instead of `== n`?

Comment: @Frank Possibly? It wasn't clear as to whether there should be a 1 if it's three or more consecutive rows, or only when it hits that three consecutive row threshold.

Comment: It is three consecutive rows that matter. If more than 3 or just 3, its not relevant. Either way this works, but results are recorded two rows lower than should be. Would need to shift it up. (e.g. when LastPrice[1] > KCT[1] AND LastPrice[2] > KCT[2] AND LastPrice[3] > KCT[3], instead of recording a 1 in Check[1]  it is recording a 1 in Check[3]). Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Comment: For some odd reason running this code and executing "check_rows(data,3)" prints "data", showing the values for data$Check, but it does not incorporate data$Check to "data". Or it does so only temporarily (on print). If that makes any sense.

Comment: @Gracos Yeah, if you wanted to permanently append the column to `data`, you'd have to say `data <- check_rows(data, 3)`.